# How to redirect cases to default Queues?

Tags: apex

the below logic which is relate to case is assigining to queues, Here I have created a custo mmetadata with queue id's and case request type fields.
the incoming case request matches with custom metadata request type then I'm redirecting to queues.

```
    But here I just wanted to check if someone has deleted queue in salesforce still the queue id is there in custom metadata. 

    How can I check if the queue id is valid before assigning to case owner feild , if queue is not present in salesforce 
    we have redirect the cases to some default queue. How can i achieve thsi logic ? Any help ?

       public static boolean changeOwner(Case caseRecord){
                try{ 
                     
                     Map<String,ET_Case_Ownership_Request_Types__mdt> ownershipMap = new Map<String,ET_Case_Ownership_Request_Types__mdt>(); 
                     
                     List<ET_Case_Ownership_Request_Types__mdt> ownershipMetadata = [select id,EMEA_Request_Types__c,Queue_Name__c,QueueId__c 
                                                 from ET_Case_Ownership_Request_Types__mdt where Queue_Name__c != null AND QueueId__c != null]; 
                                                 
                     for(ET_Case_Ownership_Request_Types__mdt obj : ownershipMetadata){
                         
                         ownershipMap.put(obj.EMEA_Request_Types__c,obj);    
                     }
                 
                     if(caseRecord.ET_Request_Type__c != null && ownershipMap.containsKey(caseRecord.ET_Request_Type__c)){               
                         
                         caseRecord.OwnerId = ownershipMap.get(caseRecord.ET_Request_Type__c).QueueId__c;
                         update caseRecord;    
                     }
                     return true;
             }Catch(Exception e){
                     return false;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd check if the queue exists first:

```
Id newQueueId = ownershipMap.get(caseRecord.ET_Request_Type__c)?.QueueId__c;
Id defaultQueueId; // populate this value somehow
Set<Id> existingQueueIds = new Map<Id, sObject>([
  SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Id IN (:newQueueId, :defaultQueueId)
]).keySet();
if(existingQueueIds.contains(newQueueId)) {
  caseRecord.OwnerId = newQueueId;
} else if(existingQueueIds.contains(defaultQueueId)) {
  caseRecord.OwnerId = defaultQueueId;
} else {
  // Handle error condition or maybe just do nothing
}
```

I strongly recommend that you consider [bulkification](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) to make your code more efficient and to avoid potential governor limit problems in the future.